# Support of Anchor IDL for enums

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, javascript, typescript

Currently I am writing smart contract code in anchor. When i declare a pub struct in smart contract I can access it in type script easily using IdlType example:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C)]
/// Stores meta information about the `Account` on chain
pub struct UserData {
    // user pk
    pub user_pk : Pubkey,
    // user balance in lamports for the game / user
    pub user_balance : u64,
}
```

can be accessed in typescript code as follows

```
type UD = anchor.IdlTypes<Program>["UserData"];
let userData : UD = account.userData;
let userBalance = data.userBalance;
```

But i am not able to do same things with enums instead of structs.

```
// rust code
enum UserType {
 client,
 employee
}

// ts code
type UT = anchor.IdlTypes<Program>["UserType"];
let userType : UT = account.userType;
assert(userType == UT.client);
```

Could you help me to find out how to use enums.

Comment: Can you share what that last TS code block does? What type do you get as `UT` and what value do you get as `userType`?

Comment: Is the interchangeable use of `data` and `account` variables intentional?

Comment: @CallumM
The type UT is as follows ```type UT = {}``` but in case of UD I have

```type UD = {
    userPk: anchor.web3.PublicKey;
    userBalance: anchor.BN;
}```

value of user type is : 
```const userType: TypeDef<{
    name: "UserType";
    type: {
        kind: "enum";
        variants: [{
            name: "client";
        }, {
            name: "employee";
        }];
    };
} & {
    name: "UserType";
}, Record<string, never>>```

Comment: @sohrab account is a variable that contains solana account which can be fetched by 
```anchor.IdlAccount<Program>``` and data is member of that account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to compare enums in typescript.

We have to define custom type:
`type UserType = {client: {}} | {employee:{}}`

then you can create a variable
`const userType : UserType = account.userType`

Then comparision goes as follows :

import loadash

`import _ from "lodash";`

Assert:

`assert(_.isEqual(userType,{client: {}}))`

Comment: i am running into a similar problem. please i would like to know what `account`(account.userType) stands for in your code

Comment: Hey I have created in form of other answer as I had problems putting it as comments.

Answer (score 3):

For example if you have an account defined in Rust code

```
#[account()]
/// Stores meta information about the `Account` on chain
pub struct User {
    // user data
    pub user_data : UserData,
    // use type
    pub user_type : UserType,
}
```

You have created an account User on solana cluster then in ts code you can fetch:

```
type UserType = {client:{}} | {employee:{}};
type User = Omit<anchor.IdlAccounts<ProgramName>["user"], "userType"> & {userType: UserType};
const user : User = await this.program.account.user.fetch(pubkey);
const userType = user.userType;
```

account is instance 'user' in this case.